# Maven add properties file to jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, properties

I am using the following plugin configuration to make a jar file and I want to include non-java src files in the same place in the output jar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509309/in-maven-how-can-i-include-non-java-src-files-in-the-same-place-in-the-output-ja).

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>   
            <!-- include non-java src files in the same place in the output jar -->
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>                                     
        </configuration>
```

The above does not work and neither does the following:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <!-- include non-java src files in the same place in the output jar -->
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>        

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>                    
        </configuration>                
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add file in the same package (folder) in `src/main/resources` instead of `src/main/java` or see my answer [With maven - clean package, xml source files are not included in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9800196/651140)

Answer (score 18):

I did it this way and function perfectly.

```
    </dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do *not* do this. Files you load at runtime from the classpath are resources, not Java code. See the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.yaml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- java 8 = 1.8 -->
                <!-- java 11 = 11 -->
                <!-- java 17 = 17 -->
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```