properties folder under src/main/resources path are not downloading from maven central when adding project dependency
I have built maven project and deployed it to maven central but project have properties files under src/main/resources path, they aren't downloading from maven when user add project dependency
I expect properties files to be downloaded automatically when user add project dependency under src/main/resources path

Have you included the resources in your build process so that they are copied into the jar file? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987633/maven-add-properties-file-to-jar-file

I have tried but the properties files they are compiled to jar, but i want them as files to be downloaded under src/main/resource to override files

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I’m not sure what you’re asking.  Generally, a Maven artifact is a .jar file.  It can contain resources as well as compiled classes.  Are you expecting something to happen other than Maven’s downloading of a .jar file containing your resources?  If you are expecting Maven to somehow directly modify your own local project, that is not how Maven works.  No build tool would do that, and there is no reason for a program to need that.  Your code can access resources from any .jar on the classpath using a getResource or getResourceAsStream call.

Looks like a XY problem https://xyproblem.info/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
