# In multimodule maven project. Need to access conf/properties file from one child to another child

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

My project is multi module

```
parent

|
-----Child A

     src/main/resources/test.conf
|
-----Child B

     src/main/test/ (from here I want to access conf)
```

I have tried multiple options:

1) Added Apache Resource Bundles (https://maven.apache.org/apache-resource-bundles/)

2) using resource tag in pom.xml
[With maven - clean package, xml source files are not included in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798955/with-maven-clean-package-xml-source-files-are-not-included-in-classpath/9800196#9800196)

Comment: One observation : I can add .properties and .xml. Only .conf is not added as part of jar

Comment: although your question seems to be answered, I would like to know how the answer respects your requirement, that you want to access `test.conf` from another child.

Comment: I have added dependencies on child B to child A. As conf is part of jar now, i can access these conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is my answer , you need to  remove exclude from pom for conf, if you have this plugin you can check

`<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${jar.plugin.version}</version>
 <configuration>
   <excludes>
     <exclude>job.xml</exclude>
   </excludes>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>`